# Argparse using optional argument with value in conjunction with positional argument

Tags: python, argparse

In my script I have, for simplicity, three arguments:

```
parser.add_argument("-c", "--compile")
parser.add_argument("--verbose", 
                    help = "stores compilation results in specified log file as they come (default name: %(const)s)", 
                    nargs = '?', 
                    const = DEFAULT_LOG_FILE_NAME, 
                    metavar = "LOGFILE_NAME")
parser.add_argument("path", nargs = "*")
```

`-c` and `--verbose` are both optional, as well as path, which is a positional argument. In addition, the argument to --verbose is also optional. If none is provided,

Say I want to combine these three in a single command.

I would run it as follows:

```
myscript.py -c --verbose path1 path2 path3
```

The problem here is that in this case, the script will interpret `path1` as an argument to `--verbose`, unless I use `--verbose=<log_name>`. As far as I have been able to find, there is no way of restricting argparse to only allowing the `=` syntax instead of a space. I cannot count on my users understanding that either `=` must be used, or put `--verbose` as one of the last arguments.

How would I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use `--` to signal the end of optional arguments; everything following is interpreted as positional arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes I read about that. However again, how would I enforce this upon my users? It's not reflected in the help text. Do I need to put it in the usage text at the top of the help?

Comment: In this case, you are overloading `--verbose` to do 2 things: as an on/off flag, and as a log file option. Consider separating it into two different options: `--verbose` and `--log=LOGFILE_NAME`

Comment: It's indeed not ideal. I'd add a *separate* option to capture a logfile: `--verbose --log=...`.

Comment: @HaiVu: Yes, that would indeed be a good solution. Consider adding an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: + for asking what the user is likely  to do - or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you are overloading --verbose to do 2 things: as an on/off flag, and as a log file option. Consider separating it into two different options: `--verbose` and `--log=LOGFILE_NAME`